# how the execution time drops sharply (more than expected) as the number of processors increase?

Tags: parallel-processing, f#, multicore

I am executing my programme 5000000 times in parallel using "Parallel.For" from F#.
Average execution time per task is given below.

Number of active cores   :     Execution Time (microseconds)

2                     :           866

4                     :          424

8                      :          210

12                    :           140

16                      :         106

24                     :          76

32                     :          60

provided the fact,

by doubling number of cores, maximum speedup which we can get, should be less than than 2 (ideally it can be 2).

what can be the reason for this sharp speedup.

Comment: The ratios are quite close to best possible, and I would dismiss any difference as measurement error,

Comment: from 32 to 16 maximum possible can be half but it is less than half. I have repeatedly done measurement and the values provided are average of all those measurement.

Comment: 60*2 > 106 this is suboptimal.  The best possible value is 53

Comment: what i was expecting, for 2 cores it is 866 so for 4 it will be more than 433, because some synchronization overhead will also be there.

Comment: Other way round - time should be >433, not <433

Comment: yes more than 433, my mistake

Comment: Voting to close, this question arises from a straightforward misunderstanding of a small set of numbers.

Comment: Remember: 1 there is overhead from the OS, including the thread scheduler; 2. there is overhead in adding threads to the thread pool, so it is only done in response to increasing queues of work items; and 3. timing precision is limited: lots of small counts will lead to accumulating rounding errors.

Comment: Can be overhead associated with JIT compiling too.

Comment: You didn't say how you were measuring the performance; this can be very significant.

Comment: @ Richard, provided these 3 overheads, timing should be more than 433 in case of 4 Cores when u see in contrast of 8 CPU.

Comment: performance is measured using stopwatch object provided by System.Diagnostic

Answer (score 0):

- 2 * 866 = 1732
- 4 * 424 = 1696
- 8 * 210 = 1680
- 12 * 140 = 1680
- 16 * 106 = 1696
- 24 * 76 = 1824
- 32 * 60 = 1920

So as you increase parallelism, relative performance improves and then begins to fall.  The improvement is possibly due to amortization of overhead costs like JIT compilation or in the algorithm that manages the parallelization.

The degradation as the degree of parallelism increases is often due to some sort of resource contention, excessive context switching, or the like.

Comment: my only doubt is ... when i have doubled number of cores, performance improvement should be less than double, as there will be some overhead. the behaviour is justified in case of more number of cores but for lesser number of cores, it is better than double, what can be the reason for it?

Comment: @anushri The detailed answer depends on how you are timing the performance.  You said in a comment that you're using stopwatch, but what I meant is to find out the specific points at which you are starting and stopping the stopwatch.  If you can edit the question to include some sample code, it might be possible to see.  Alternatively you can use a profiler, which may allow you to measure directly.